# Active record result and transformed JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I need to transform active record JSON to something like this:

```
{
       cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
                {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],
       rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]},
              {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]},
              {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]},
              {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]},
              {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}
             ]
}
```

That is totally different from what to_json returns from activerecord. What is the most ruby way to transform JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the to_json method in your model

```
# your_model.rb, implement an instance method to_json
def to_json(options = {})
  {
    'cols' => [{'id' => 'whateveryoulike'}],
    'rows' => [{'id' => 'whateveryoulike'}]
  }.to_json(options)
end
```

Remember, it is important to accept `options` as parameter to this method and pass it on to `to_json` of the hash (or any other `to_json` call you make inside this method, for that matter). Otherwise, the method may not behave as expected on collection JSON serialization. And of course since you haven't given any details as to what your model is and how it maps to the desired JSON response, you will have to implement the representation of cols and rows as you like.

This also applies to `to_xml`.